# Which one is better way to insert data?

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql, query-performance

I have two cases

1. case

   ```
   create  proc    createEmployee
       @firstName varchar(255),
       @lastName varchar(255) = null
   as
   insert into Employee_Tbl values (@firstName, @lastName)
   ```
2. case

   ```
   create  proc    createEmployee
       @firstName varchar(255),
       @lastName varchar(255) = null
   as
   insert into Employee_Tbl(FirstName) values (@firstName)

   declare @id as int
   set @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
   if @lastName is not null
   begin
      update Employee_Tbl
          set LastName  = @lastName 
       where EmpId = @id
   end
   ```

Of the two code blocks above, which one performs better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identical inputs, intended identical results, though the second is going to fail if whatever the second field in Employee_Tbl is NOT NULL without a default!

Additionally, the second should be using the [OUTPUT clause](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx), not SCOPE_IDENTITY, for [various reasons](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1068641-392-1.aspx) - including bugs in SCOPE_IDENTITY (connect link's gone, though).

The first one is an Insert which will put in an entire row.

The Insert + Update is going to put in an entire row, then sometimes try to find that row in the table and update that row with a larger value.  If it does this and the page was full and it's a VARCHAR or NVARCHAR, you're going to get a page split no the update as well.

You'd have to check it in Profiler, but if @lastname is NULL, I'd expect the first to have essential equal performance to the second (IF the second isn't throwing an error about a missing value!).  If @lastname is NOT NULL, I'd expect the first to wipe the floor with the second (i.e. the first will be much faster).

Answer (score 2):

First of all , The stored procedures you have are totally different. So the performance are not really compare-able.

Thought the final output you receive is the same , in the first SP you are doing a simple insert where as in second SP you are inserting and then doing an update.
So it is pretty obvious that the second procedure is doing more work